# pandas, json data format in .txt file, merge

Tags: json, pandas, merge, glob, subdirectory

I want to merge the data from multiple directories in one folder.
I have "application_data.txt" file written in json format in multiple directories in one parent directory.
I want to merge the data from all the subdirectories and create a dataframe for further analysis.

code:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Find all the folders
root_dir = Path('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/fd249093-60d2-4d4f-99d0-3e98954f7711')
folders = [fld for fld in root_dir.iterdir() if fld.is_dir()]

# Find all the file names
all_filenames = []
for fld in folders:
    for f in fld.glob('*application_data.txt'):
        all_filenames.append(f.name)


for f in list(set(all_filenames)):
    app_data = pd.DataFrame({})

    for fld in folders:
        if (fld / f).is_file():
           with open(fld /f, 'r') as fp:
             application_data = json.load(fp)
             temp_df = pd.DataFrame(application_data)
             app_data = app_data.append(temp_df)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for, here?

Comment: I want to know if this is the right way to do it or not. and is there any better way?Getting an error message : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Comment: Hey, if you will edit the question and attach your current directory structure, the json format you have and the desired output, it will help us to help you.

Comment: Hey, I solved the issue, there was a problem with the data. Thanks for your response